# Create file name on basis of output of the command

Tags: unix

I have a question on creating file name on basis of output we get on running a command. Below is the example

Have 2 records like below

cat test1.txt

Unable to find Solution

### Can you please help

And I am running below command to get the last word from the first line and i want to have file name to be that name(Last word name)

cat test1.txt | head -1 | awk '{ print $NF }'

Solution

Can you please help me to get the file name as a last word name

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace "Solution" with "test1.txt" in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to redirect your output to a file and have the filename from the first line of your output, you can use

```
outfile=""
your_command | while read line; do
   if [ -z "${outfile}" ]; then
      outfile=$(echo "${line}"| awk '{ print $NF }')
   fi
   echo "${line}" >> ${outfile}
done
```

Comment: Thanks Walter, I have used other way to do it.

Comment: However I have one more question 

How to collect exit code and output of the script?
.abc.sh > abc.txt
echo $?
in above sample I will get exit code of redirection command but not of script, but i want to collect both. how to do this?

Comment: abc.sh and the redirection is seen as one command with one exit code. Try with `rm x > y; echo $?` and `rm x > /y/y` with x existing and not existing.
You can try to `touch` abc.txt before redirction but you don't catch other failures like a full partition with it. One possibility is changing abc.sh, and write the exit code of abc.sh to a file. When the total exitcode is 0, you can ignore (remove) the file. When the total exitcode > 0, you can see what your tmp file says.